# Indesign and Extendscript: Multiple functions, loops, and timing. Function called in a loop, not in sync

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Key problem is that function in a loop is out of sync. I don't get the correct `var myDimensions` unless I include the alert() to slow down the process. I'm not sure if I need to use callbacks. I read about them and find them confusing and I want to avoid callback hell. What's happening is that when running a function in a loop, some of my other function calls are out of sync. **I am writing this JavaScript as Extendscript for Adobe InDesign so Extendscript does not include modern JS.**

I discovered the timing issue after adding an `alert()` in the function to return the value to confirm I was getting the correct values. If I add the `alert()` it causes a delay which makes the code run correctly. When I remove `alert()` it fails again. I've tried to simplify my code for brevity below instead of pasting the full 1,500 line file.

```
function calculateSomething(podValue){
  return podValue + 1;
}

function doPodStuff(value){
  return value;
}

function getDimensions(calculation){
  return calculation * 2;
}

function pod(value, count){
  var podStuff;
  var calculation;
  var myDimensions;
  podStuff = doPodStuff(value);
  calculation = calculateSomething(podStuff):
  myDimensions = getDimensions(calculation);
  /* this is where my timing is off and podStuff and calculation get out of sync,
  I determined this after placing an alert(myDimensions) right here If I add the alert(),
  the delay makes it work, when I remove alert() it fails again.
  */
  return myDimensions;
}

function row(value, count){
  var myPod;
  for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
    myPod = pod(value, 2);
  }
  return myPod;
}

row('foobar', 4);
```

My goal is to have the `pod()` function run in the `for()` loop but not out of order. How do I synchronize or make sure the timing is correct?

Comment: Do all first three functions return the same `value`? Seems unlikely (and redundant if true) and makes things confusing. You may want to take some time to [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) for help in creating a clearer MCVE

Comment: If the problem starts after call geDimensions, it's probabily that the problem resides in getDimensions definition. Are you using shared global variables inside those functions?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Sorry, I suppose I sacrificed readability for brevity. That's on me. I can edit if that helps. I'll definitely read your link.

Comment: @Miguel, after some thinking it seems that running functions from a loop causes the timing to get off so instead of asynchronous, I'm thinking how to format to run synchronously. Since I'm in InDesign, I can't normally use a promise like I typically would in other JavaScript projects and I was trying to avoid callback hell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to chain your functions:

```
function pod(value, count) {
    return getDimensions(calculateSomething(doPodStuff(value))) }
```

And in any case you can use `$.sleep(1000)` instead of `alert("...")` to slow your script down.